# get header with todo keyword

Tags: org-ql

```
* one 
* two
** books
*** IN-PROGRESS book1 
*** book2 
*** book3
* three
* four
** five
*** books
**** book4
```

How to get:

1. all headings title with todo-'IN-PROGRESS' keyword which are children of heading 'books'

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in just one file? Or all your agenda files?

Comment: only one file :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing is to use `isearch` and look for `IN-PROGRESS`, then eyeball the heading to see if it's in a `books` hierarchy. Org mode files are plain text, so everything that applies to text applies to them as well.

But assuming you want an Org mode specific method, here's a simple example implementation in the context of a slightly  augmented version (adding a `TODO` list at the top and two more instances to test the matching) of your file:

```el
#+TODO: START IN-PROGRESS | DONE

* one 
* two
** books
*** IN-PROGRESS book1 
*** book2 
*** book3
* three
** IN-PROGRESS book-not-3
* four
** five
*** books
**** book4
**** IN-PROGRESS book5
     
*  Code                                                       :noexport:

  #+begin_src emacs-lisp :results drawer
    (defun ndk/select-heading ()
       (if (member "books" (org-get-outline-path))
          (org-get-heading t t t t)))

    (org-map-entries 'ndk/select-heading "/+TODO=\"IN-PROGRESS\"" 'file)
  #+end_src
```

**Explanation**:

- `org-map-entries` takes a function and applies it on all entries that match a criterion in a given scope (here, the entries that match the `TODO` state `IN-PROGRESS` in the scope of the whole file). The matching is explained in the [Matchings Tags and Properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties) section of the Org mode manual. In this case, we match every entry in the file whose `TODO` state is `IN-PROGRESS` and on each one, we apply the function `ndk/select-heading`.
- The function `ndk/select-heading` is called at the beginning of each matching entry. It first gets the `breadcrumbs` of the entry, i.e. the path of headings leading from the top level to the entry as a list, and then checks whether `books` is a member of the list, i.e. whether the entry is a sub-entry of a `books` entry. If so, it returns the current heading, shorn of all extras (`TODO` state, tags, etc).

If you press `C-c C-c` on the code block to run it, it will return `("book1" nil "book5")`, the first and last entries  matching the state and being sub-entries of `books`, while the `nil` comes from an entry matching the state but which is *not* a sub-entry of `books` (the entry `book-not-3` in the file).

Two more things:

- The match specification has a short-cut form: instead of saying `"+TODO=\"FOO\""`, you can say `/+FOO`. But the match specification also allows the form `/+FOO-BAR` to specify that you want to match `FOO` but *NOT* `BAR`. That precludes your using the short form in your case because `/+IN-PROGRESS` would mean: match `IN` but *NOT* `PROGRESS` which is not what you want. So you have to use the long form or rename your states so that they don't contain dashes.
- The search above is tailored to your exact criteria at the cost of hardwiring the values you are looking for into the code. It's not hard to write a more general function that takes these things as arguments, but it does complicate the code a bit, so I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader. If you understand the code above and have a little Lisp under your belt, you should be able to write the generalization easily.
- It's also easy to get rid of any `nil` entries in the result if you don't want them: just say `(delete nil (org-map-entries ....))`.

Note that `org-map-entries` is a very powerful function: it's a good idea to read its doc string with `C-h f org-map-entries` and also read the [Using the Mapping API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html#Using-the-Mapping-API) section in the manual.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach could be using [org-ql](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql). Here an example that should match your original question:

```
(require 'org-ql)

(org-ql-query
  :select #'org-get-heading
  :from "/tmp/so.org"
  :where '(and (todo "IN-PROGRESS")
               (parent "books")))
```

- The `:select` key denotes the function that will be called on each entry matching the predicate in the `:where` condition
- `/tmp/so.org` is the name of the file where I saved the content prepared by @NickD